# Choosing different layout file for sinatra-authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, view, sinatra, haml

`sinatra-authentication` expects a `layout.haml` for its pre-rolled authentication views.

How do I specify a different layout template that `sinatra-authentication` can use (e.g. `auth_layout.haml`) so that I can keep `layout.haml` for my app's views?

My current not-ideal approach to this is to:

- Allow `sinatra-authentication` to use the standard `layout.haml`
- Explicitly use another layout file (e.g. `std_layout.haml`) in all other parts of the app

e.g.

```
...
erb :home_page, :layout => :std_layout
...
```

I'd prefer it the other way around :)

Answer (score 0):

You may read [on Layout Engines](http://www.sinatrarb.com/blog) or simply try:

```
get '/login' do
  haml :login, layout: auth_layout
end
```

EDIT-1: your comment is Ok `layout: auth_layout` is ruby 1.9 syntax `:layout => auth_layout` is syntax used before 1.9

And if you are talking about [this sinatra-authentication](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication) you must hack [this file](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/blob/master/lib/sinatra-authentication.rb)'s  `app.get '/login/?'` method regarding (Module::Helpers#use_layout?).

EDIT-2: I guess overwriting `use_layout?` method will help you, perhaps something like

```
Module Sinatra
  Module Helpers
    def use_layout?
       request.xhr? ? false : :auth_layout
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The above code didn't work as `login.haml` is being invoked within `sinatra-authentication`. Also the `layout:` syntax doesn't seem to match syntax on http://www.sinatrarb.com/blog

Comment: Thanks again @kfl62 :) Yes, I looked through the source before but don't know how to change the code to use another layout file. Any suggestions or code would be most helpful :)